# Generate Random Letters Depending on User Input

Tags: c++

I have to make a simple letter guessing game. So far I've finished almost everything but I'm not sure about what to do when it comes to one task.
So before the game begins it asks the user to input two things:

> Enter the amount of different characters: (if 4 is entered for example, the letters chosen would be from A to the 4th letter, A-D only)

and

> Enter the pattern length:

The pattern length input is working fine, but I'm having a tough time figuring out how to modify the generate code function to add the amount of different characters.

Any tips?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

size_t len;
string str;

void generate_code()
{
    str.string::reserve(len);

    random_device rd;
    mt19937 gen{rd()};
    uniform_int_distribution<char> dis{'A', 'Z'};

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) 
    {
        str += dis(gen);
    }
}

void guess_checker()
{
    string guess{};
    size_t trial_count = 0, match_count = 0;
    do 
    {
        cout << "Enter your guess: " << endl;
        cin >> guess;
        if (guess.size() != len) 
        {
            cout << "error: invalid guess" << endl;
        } 
        else 
        {
            match_count = 0;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) 
            {
                if (guess[i] == str[i])
                ++match_count;
            }
            cout << "You guessed " << match_count << " character"
              << (match_count == 1 ? "" : "s") << " correctly." << endl;
        }
        ++trial_count;
   } 
   while (match_count != len);
   cout << "You guessed the pattern in " << trial_count << " guess"
     << (trial_count == 1 ? "" : "es") << "." << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int amount;

    cout << "Enter the amount of different characters: ";
    cin >> amount;
    cout << "Enter the pattern length: ";
    cin >> len;
    generate_code();
    guess_checker();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `str.string::reserve(len);` You don't need to disambiguate, so just use `str.reserve(len);` :P

Comment: If you want to change the limits of your distribution, I guess you would want to modify the upper bound of your distribution. Perhaps `'A'` to `'A' + amount` instead of `'A'` to `'Z'`.

Comment: I would recommend getting used to passing information to functions through arguments rather than by making your variables global.

Comment: 'A' to 'A' + amount instead of 'A' to 'Z' I tried that but it didnt work for some reason. @FrançoisAndrieux

Comment: @Sammour "It didn't work" is a poor descriptor. How didn't it work?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Sorry about that, my school's compiler gives me this warning for some reason: **warning: narrowing conversion of ‘((65 + amount) - 1)’ from ‘int’ to ‘char’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]** but it does work on other online compilers, any idea why?

Comment: A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion from a type to a smaller (narrower) type. In this case `int` to `char`. The expression `(65 + amount) - 1` yields an `int`, which is being crammed into a smaller `char`. To remove the warning, explicitly cast to `char` with `static_cast<char>( (65 + amount) - 1 )` to tell the compiler you are aware of the conversion. The 65 looks suspicious to me since it's equal to `'A'`. If you are using numeric constants, know that you can use the matching character instead. `'A' + amount - 1` is pretty much equivalent to '65 + amount - 1'.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your generator line to:

```
uniform_int_distribution<char> dis{'A', 'A' + amount - 1};
```

I would also recommend adding some validation beforehand, such as:

```
if (amount < 1 || amount > 26) {
    cout << "Bad amount" << endl;
    // exit or something
}
```